# System metrics not support for postgresql. Skipping processing

Tags: postgresql, airflow, database-administration

I am trying to get some sample data from all the tables from my postgres DB. I am running the profiler job from airflow. I am getting below error

```
{system.py:65} INFO - System metrics not support for postgresql. Skipping processing.
```

any input would be great.

thank you

Comment: Can you please provide some code to understand the source of your problem?

Comment: I am calling profiler job from open metadata tool. it will collect 2 % of sample from each table. I did not write any custom code